# What is the JavaFX KeyCode for the character: `

Tags: javafx

What is the JavaFX KeyCode for the character: `   ?

I have tried searching KeyCode and the only candidate I see is "BACK_QUOTE", but that seems to correspond to `À` according to this (probably an encoding issue).

```
System.out.println ( KeyCode.BACK_QUOTE.getChar() );
```

In either case, I don't think that represents ` and I can't find any other candidates.

```
KeyCode.getKeyCode( "`" )
```

returns `null`, so that's wierd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When listening for `KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED` events it gives me `KeyCode.BACK_QUOTE` as the code when I press the <kbd>`</kbd> key.

```
// Prints BACK_QUOTE
primaryStage.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, event -> System.out.println(event.getCode()));
```

If I listen to `KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED` events the character is ` when I type <kbd>`</kbd>.

```
// Prints `
primaryStage.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED, event -> System.out.println(event.getCharacter()));
```

However, I also get `À` from `KeyCode.BACK_QUOTE.getChar()`. I'm not sure why there's an inconsistency, but it appears the `KeyCode` for ` is `BACK_QUOTE`.

Comment: Interestingly, tilde seems to be missing as well.